# How to display two annotations with the same coordinates on the map?

Tags: ios

I have two annotations with the same coordinates. And I have to display them on the map. When I add these annotations on the map I see just one pin. How can I display two annotations instead of one? Or how can I display a annotations list by clicking on the pin? Can anybody help me?
Thanks in advance.
Igor

Answer (score 1):

When you try to display multiple annotations at the same coordinate on a map using MapKit, generally it will actually place two different pins, but they will be in the exact same location. You can compare the difference in the shadow strength to see the difference, however; look at a single pin's shadow, then look at your double-pin shadow, and you should see the latter appear darker.

In terms of indicating to your user that there are multiple pins, there are several ways you could do that. You might consider implementing the `title` or `subtitle` properties on your annotations to display the number of annotations at the same coordinates (e.g. set `subtitle` to the string `@"(and two more)"` or similar). Then, when the callout accessory view is tapped, push (onto a navigation controller stack) a table view of annotations at that location.

Comment: Tim, but how can I find out what annotations push onto navigation controller stack? Because there are a lot of annotations on the map.
Is any way to show annotation list as popup?
Thanks.

Comment: That depends entirely on how you're storing your map data or annotations in your view controller - you'll need to filter the annotations to get a list of only those that share the same coordinate as the selected annotation. You could show the list as a custom callout from the annotation - [this link](http://blog.asolutions.com/2010/09/building-custom-map-annotation-callouts-part-1/) seems to describe how.